# D3 - Using a variable as file path

Tags: d3.js

How does one pass a variable into a D3 file path?

`d3.csv($LQ_type, function (error, data){... //open up the cluster data file`

where $LQ_type is the dynamic file path.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The variable must be contained in square brackets.

ie/

d3.csv([$LQ_type], function (error, data){...

Comment: Yes, you figured it out. When you put it inside square brackets, it's evaluated. For instance, suppose you have this pair in an object named data:  { 50th : "foo" }. You can't access it using data.50th, because 50th is not a valid name. But you can do it using data["50th"]. It's the same principle.